# How can I change levels in Theme Hospital

Tags: theme-hospital

Between levels six and seven, I clicked the wrong part of the level select screen and got dropped back onto the first level. No matter what I do, I can't get back to where I was -- if I quit back to the main menu, the 'continue previous game' option drops me back to level 1.

**How do you go back to the level select screen?** Do I need to fully replay the first level? Or am I now stuck replaying back to where I was?

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate. This question is asking for clarification on a (misleading) answer on a previous question and should have been a comment.

Comment: Nope. I am stuck on level 1, as I mentioned in my last paragraph, having actually transitioned there by misclicking after level six (and the intervening rat level.) I clearly mentioned this in my last paragraph. Just because I got to this point while following a different answer doesn't make it a dupe because I am now in a clearly different situation.

Comment: **I am not on a rat level; how does the question about the rat level help me get back to where I was in the level progression?**

Comment: This is much clearer and I know the bug you're talking about. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this.

The first is to press C on the level advancement screen (with the board game). This allows you to click on the level you want to play. Annoyingly, it can cause the mouse to disappear, making it difficult to click the level you want.

Your other option is to use cheats. Open a message and enter 24328 on the fax machine and press the green button. This will enable cheats. With cheats enabled, press F12 to automatically win the level. Skip your way to the level you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a third way to do it as well; via a command line parameter. If 'xx' is your desired level, launch the game using:

`hospital.exe -Lxx`

For example, to get to level number 6;

`hospital.exe -L06`

For more information read [this resource](http://www.eudoxus.demon.co.uk/thc/cheat.htm).